# Issue with $ARCH variable

Tags: linux

I am using a `.sh` script and it requires the `$ARCH` variable. When I type

```
echo $ARCH
```

nothing shows up on screen. How can I make this variable work ?

Comment: What is that variable supposed to contain? It's not something that is common.

Comment: I guess the result of command `arch`, that is in my case `i686`. It is for installing a fortran90 program called f90split. The line in the `.sh` involving `$ARCH` goes like this : 
`mv a.out ~/bin/$ARCH/f90split`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `sh`, `bash` or `zsh`:

```
export ARCH=i686
```

In `csh` or `tcsh`:

```
setenv ARCH i686
```

In Windows `cmd.exe`:

```
set ARCH=i686
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I just added `export ARCH=i686` in my `.bashrc` and it is working perfectly !

Comment: @vanna: Perhaps use `export ARCH=$(arch)` or `export ARCH=$(uname -m)` instead, if you intend to have this in `.bashrc` or similar.